# What is maximum revision capacity of IDE's local History Manager? How can i configure it (want to enlarge)?

Tags: delphi

Entire question (actually, almost two) fit into the title line, so i dont see the point of further rhetoric. Unhappy with pithiness? Go to the [Athens](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/History_Manager)! :-)

Comment: @Downvoter, leave the shadows!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"File backup limit" in [Editor Options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Editor_Options). "Create backup files" have to be checked. Configurable between 1 - 90.

Comment: About 1 minute faster than me!

Comment: Actually my calculations reveals what saving every 30 min. will exhaust 90 revisions maximum in 6 (rounded up) working days.

Comment: it would be cool if you could actually go above 90 on this feature.

Comment: If only there were some tool that could allow us to keep track of an *arbitrary* number of past revisions of something. Someone should really invent something like that.

Comment: @user - I know this probably does not have any practical value, but the limit is imposed on the options dialog, not the actual implementation which refers to `HKCU\Software\Borland(?)\BDS\#.0\Editor\Options\File Backup Level`. Tested with '125' with D2007, no problem. Will revert to '90' when Editor Options is applied next time however.

Comment: @Sertac, thanks, worth to know about! @Warren P, yeah, exactly my point (i understand practical reasons behind the limit, but thinks it set too low)

Comment: Perhaps I was too oblique in my previous comment. If you're worried about losing your work from more than 90 revisions ago or more than a week ago, you need to change your source-control habits. Check in your code more often, and then you can look back at as many previous versions as you want and from however long ago you want.

Comment: Agree about version control..... so... You know what would be cool, is an hourly-auto-shelving feature in my version control client.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, i disagree about 90 revisions, it is a tiny number. However, agree what number of automatic check-ins should be finite *ideologically*

Comment: If they bother to create the backup feature, why they limit it to 90? Even if a user should use other methods of backup (source control as Rob suggests), why to put a extra line of code to check if the number is higher than 90, when some people will prefer a higher value ?????? It is like limiting the speed of a turbo car to 30Km/h just because we can do it.